# Retrieve most recent mysql entry

Tags: mysql

I have a project table and a task table. I want to retrieve a list of projects and then for each project display the task with the latest due_date.

The code below works for displaying the projects and will retrieve one task but it wont seem to retrieve the task with the latest due_date and instead seems to retrieve the task with the lowest id primary key. If I allow more than one task to show the results are ordered by due_date but I want to limit them to one.

```
SELECT t.*, p.id as project_id, p.name as project_name, p.archive as project_archive
FROM project p
JOIN user_project up ON p.id = up.project AND up.user = '.$user.'
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tmp.* FROM
(SELECT *, IF( @prev <> project_id, @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, @prev := project_id
FROM task t
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
WHERE user_id = '.$user.' 
ORDER BY t.project_id) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.rank <= 1) AS t ON p.id = t.project_id
ORDER BY p.id asc, t.due_date desc
```

Comment: This is the same problem that everyone else is having. Why not see how they solved it?

Comment: By "latest" you mean "the maximum due_date for each project"?

Comment: HI Barranka yes maximum due_date is what I want. Its held as a date format in the table

Comment: Strawberry I have searched and searched for this. If there is something similar please post a link or let me know what I should be searching for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that tried to help. I eventually solved this by changing the line

```
ORDER BY t.project_id) AS tmp
```

to

```
ORDER BY t.project_id, t.due_date desc) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Is possible that this query can help you

```
SELECT *
FROM project p
JOIN user_project up ON p.id = up.project AND up.user = '.$user.'
left join task on p.id = task.project_id and 
task.due_date = (select max(due_date) from task where project_id = p.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I get `Unknown column 't.project_id' in 'on clause'`

Answer (score 1):

`$`SELECT *
FROM project p
JOIN user_project up ON p.id = up.project AND up.user = '.$user.'
left join task on p.id = task.project_id and 
task.due_date = (select max(due_date) from task where project_id = p.id)`$`

Comment: This solution half works for me. It does exactly what I asked for in the question BUT it also removes a bunch of the code that is getting the data from the tasks table. I am trying to combine the code but not having much luck so far.